# Reversing the bits of a 32-bit integer

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, integer, bitwise

Here is my code:

```
noTest=int(input())
reverse=[]
nums=[]
for i in range(noTest):
    nums.append(int(input())) 

for num in nums:
    binary=bin(num)
    binNum=binary[2:]
    rev=binNum[::-1]
    rev=binary[:2]+rev+'0'*(32-len(rev))
    #print int(rev,2)
    reverse.append(int(rev,2))

for r in reverse:
    print(r)
```

**Input:**
The first line of input consists number of the test cases. Each test case
contains a single 32 bit integer.

**Output:**
Print the reverse of integer.

```
Input:00000000000000000000000000000001 =1
Output:10000000000000000000000000000000 =2147483648
```

Comment: `I have...` to what purpose? Know [bit hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel)?

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Caridorc's answer, you can merge `bin` and `zfill` when using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). Which gives a much cleaner read IMO:

```
int('{:032b}'.format(num)[::-1], 2)
```

Alternately you can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format), which would be:

```
int(format(num, '032b')[::-1], 2)
```

Comment: `int(format(num, '032b')[::-1], 2)`

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid building a list of results to print them after, you can just print them as you calculate them.

Also you assign a lot of variables and:

```
binNum=binary[2:]
```

is not explicit in removing the '0b' that Python prefixes, better is

```
.replace('0b','')
```

Also the padding with 0 logic that you write is already implemented in the `zfill` function, so you can avoid re-writing it yourself.

Finally, you should write a function to read the input to separate concerns and maybe reuse it in a similar problem.

Here are all my suggestions implemented.

```
def read_numbers(n):
    return [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]

for i in read_numbers( int(input()) ):
    binary_padded = bin(i).replace('0b','').zfill(32)
    print( int( binary_padded[::-1], 2) )
```

Comment: `replace` is worse since it does a search and traverses the whole string.

Comment: @Veedrac I think you are right, probably in this case [:2] should be used and maybe just adding a comment to explain the removal of '0b'